# Dealing with concurrency when inserting row with foreign key

Tags: postgresql

Assume i have a table `users`, with `uid` as primary key, and another called `sessions`, which has a column which references the related user, as a foreign key. Due to various reasons (design decisions, laws, etc), users can delete their account. As they only need some valid auth (users can login from multiple different devices), i don't see a way that this deletion can't happen at "virtually any time"<sup>1</sup>. Although being very rare, i don't see a way around dealing with all the concurrency issues it brings.

Now, when a user login is received, i get the user from the database, check the password, and then want to insert a new session. However, by then, the user could theoretically already not exist anymore.

What i am therefore currently doing, is locking the related user's row, and then doing an insert:

```
INSERT INTO sessions SELECT uid, $2, $3 FROM users WHERE uid = $1 FOR KEY SHARE;
```

I am not very proficient in sql, and while the above should work (i don't know a good way to force the issue in a test), it looks quite odd to me, to select something just for a lock, especially when the case where it got deletes is an extreme edge-case.

Is the above acceptable (does it work?), and what are normal methods of solving such issues, which i'd figure happen on a daily basis, given the concurrent nature of things, and any non-trivial query not being atomic? Is it more normal in sql to have an exception-driven flow, where one just tries to insert, and then catches the error of a foreign key, that doesn't exist? I typically reserve exceptions exclusively for "bugs in code", and even switching to `ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`, and catching exceptions for retries, is kind of weird to me.

---

[1]: I could suspend users that get deleted, and only really remove them in a different "mode", e.g. a weekly server maintenance. However, this adds a different kind of complexity, which would rather be avoided.

Comment: [Somewhat related Q&A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205425/sql-difference-optimistic-reading-and-optimistic-writing/205441#205441).

Comment: "*However, by then, the user could theoretically already not exist anymore.*" - shrug. That would throw an exception as the FK constraint is violated. Just be prepared to handle that.

Comment: The more i read and hear, the more i understand, that the meta in sql/postgres is less strict when it comes to exceptions. I should embrace them more as "rare but possible return values", then things work better. As mentioned, i typically only use exceptions for unforeseen problems, e.g. code bugs, thrown from assertions. Therefore, my brain refused to accept an exception for a case which i could foresee while writing.